# Вывод массива в list view

Tags: java, android

Я вывожу данные из *SQLite* при помощи сл. кода:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("Messeg",null,null,null,null,null,null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
       dataMess.setText(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"))+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fr"))+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("t")));
    }
} else {
    dataMess.setText("no table");
}
```

Последняя занесенная запись выводится в `text view`. Я пытаюсь вывести все записи из БД в `list view`.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените имена таблиц и содержимого, и примерно так выводятся в ListView данные из DB.

```
private Cursor cursor;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

...

ListView mListHead = findViewById(R.id.list_heads);

try {
        SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DBSQLiteOpenHelper(this);
        db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(MY_TABLE,
                new String[]{"_id", "Content1", "Content2"},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.layout_heads,
                cursor,
                new String[]{"Content1", "Content2"},
                new int[] {R.id.text_one, R.id.text_two});

        mListHead.setAdapter(listAdapter);

} catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```